# Sprite Kit Contact Detection

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Basically I have the ground, the player (raymond), and coins.
When the player touches the ground nothing should happen, game continues as normal. When the player comes in contact with the coin, I want it to print to console "coin contact with player".

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32 {
    case Raymond = 1
    case Object = 2
    case Coin = 3
}
```

Raymonds physics

```
raymond.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: raymondTexture.size().height/2)
    raymond.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

    raymond.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Raymond.rawValue
    raymond.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    raymond.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
```

Coins Physics

```
        coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: raymondTexture.size().height/2)
    coin.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

    coin.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Coin.rawValue
    coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Raymond.rawValue
    coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
```

Ground Physics if you need

```
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
    ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
```

Heres the contact function I have, I know its wrong and I need help with how to detect the coin and raymond touching.

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("coin contact with player")

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more of your code, preferably when you state the physics

Comment: @OrenEdrich done.

Comment: you are not using bitmasks correctly, 3 means 00000000000000000000000000000011 which really means Object & Raym0nd.  You need to work in powers of 2, so the next viable number is 4 (1,2,4,8,16,32)  If you want to make it readable, then use (1 << 2) for your coin (1 << 0) for your object, and (1 << 1) for your Raymond

Answer (score 1):

There really is several ways of checking this, Here are 2 of the most basics ways to get you started. The first checks name for contact, and the second checks the CategoryBitMask. It is worth noting that if your PhysicsBodies bitmasks are not set properly contact may never be reported between 2 objects.

> Edit Make sure the Scene conforms to SKPhysicsContactDelegate

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

...

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactAName = contact.bodyA.node?.name
    let contactBName = contact.bodyB.node?.name

    if (contactAName == "raymond") || (contactBName == "raymond") {

         if (contactAName == "coin") || (contactBName == "coin") {
             print("coin contact with player")
             return
        }
    }

    //or

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Coin || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Coin {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Raymond || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Raymond {
            print("coin contact with player")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, are my Physicsbodies set correctly?

Comment: they appear to be. You don't need the rawValue on the end though

Comment: alright, well when raymond and the coins touch, it doesnt print to console.

Comment: check my edit, also it looks like your didBegin func has a typo

Comment: I already had it like this,  class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

Comment: did you check that you have an underscore in your didBegin func?

Comment: Whenever a delegate function fails to fire, the first thing to check is whether the delegate was set. I've now seen _several_ tutorials that say 'declare the scene as SKPhysicsContactDelegate but which omit      self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self (usually in  didMove(to view: SKView)). Just to save the next person from wondering.